# Custom config file with eclipse microprofile-config

Tags: java, microprofile

I want to select .properties file at runtime. Is it possible with microprofile-config? So, instead of using META-INF/microprofile-config.properties I would like to use an external file:

```
java -jar mymicroprofileapp.jar -s my.properties
```

I know, it is possible to write custom config source, but I wonder if there is a built-in option to define the config file and so avoiding repeating the code in each project

Answer (score 1):

[The web site](https://microprofile.io/project/eclipse/microprofile-config) tells us the three options:

- `System.getProperties()`
- `System.getenv()`
- `META-INF/microprofile-config.properties`.

I addition to these you can register `ConfigSources`.

There is no build-in option for what you want.